# A company can set some fields not required and not visible - how can I validate it?

Tags: c#

Each company can set some fields not required and not visible but only some. I have in a database information which fields can be set not required and not visible:

```
public enum Field
{
    UserEmail,
    UserIdentifier,
    UserName
}

public class GeneralFieldSettings
{
    public Field Field { get; set; }
    public bool CanSetIfIsRequired { get; set; }
    public bool CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite { get; set; }
}

List<GeneralFieldSettings> generalFieldSettings = new List<GeneralFieldSettings>();
generalFieldSettings.Add(new GeneralFieldSettings
{
    Field = Field.UserEmail,
    CanSetIfIsRequired = false,
    CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite = false
});
generalFieldSettings.Add(new GeneralFieldSettings
{
    Field = Field.UserIdentifier,
    CanSetIfIsRequired = true,
    CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite = true
});
generalFieldSettings.Add(new GeneralFieldSettings
{
    Field = Field.UserName,
    CanSetIfIsRequired = true,
    CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite = false
});
```

Then I get data from api:

```
public class CompanyFieldSettings
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Field Field { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisibleOnWebsite { get; set; }
}

CompanyFieldSettings companyFieldSettings = new CompanyFieldSettings
{
    CompanyId = 1,
    Field = Field.UserEmail,
    IsRequired = false,
    IsVisibleOnWebsite = false
};

switch (companyFieldSettings.Field)
{
    case Field.UserEmail:
        GeneralFieldSettings generalFieldSetting1 = generalFieldSettings.Single(x => x.Field == Field.UserEmail);
        if (generalFieldSetting1.CanSetIfIsRequired == false && companyFieldSettings.IsRequired == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT required");
        if (generalFieldSetting1.CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite == false && companyFieldSettings.IsVisibleOnWebsite == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT visible on website");
        break;
    case Field.UserIdentifier:
        GeneralFieldSettings generalFieldSetting2 = generalFieldSettings.Single(x => x.Field == Field.UserIdentifier);
        if (generalFieldSetting2.CanSetIfIsRequired == false && companyFieldSettings.IsRequired == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT required");
        if (generalFieldSetting2.CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite == false && companyFieldSettings.IsVisibleOnWebsite == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT visible on website");
        break;
    case Field.UserName:
        GeneralFieldSettings generalFieldSetting3 = generalFieldSettings.Single(x => x.Field == Field.UserName);
        if (generalFieldSetting3.CanSetIfIsRequired == false && companyFieldSettings.IsRequired == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT required");
        if (generalFieldSetting3.CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite == false && companyFieldSettings.IsVisibleOnWebsite == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT visible on website");
        break;
}
```

I wonder if I can change this switch to something more elegant? Is a strategy pattern a proper direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit:

As [@JohnWu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2791540/john-wu) suggested in the comments section, you can get rid of the `switch` statement altogether and just write:

```
GeneralFieldSettings generalFieldSetting = generalFieldSetttings.Single(x => x.Field == companyFieldSettings.Field);
if (!generalFieldSetting.CanSetIfIsRequired && !companyFieldSettings.IsRequired)
    throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT required");
if (!generalFieldSetting.CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite && !companyFieldSettings.IsVisibleOnWebsite)
    throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT visible on website");
```

---

### Original answer:

One thing you could do here is refactor:

```
switch (companyFieldSettings.Field)
{
    case Field.UserEmail:
        GeneralFieldSettings generalFieldSetting1 = generalFieldSettings.Single(x => x.Field == Field.UserEmail);
        if (generalFieldSetting1.CanSetIfIsRequired == false && companyFieldSettings.IsRequired == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT required");
        if (generalFieldSetting1.CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite == false && companyFieldSettings.IsVisibleOnWebsite == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT visible on website");
        break;
    case Field.UserIdentifier:
        GeneralFieldSettings generalFieldSetting2 = generalFieldSettings.Single(x => x.Field == Field.UserIdentifier);
        if (generalFieldSetting2.CanSetIfIsRequired == false && companyFieldSettings.IsRequired == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT required");
        if (generalFieldSetting2.CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite == false && companyFieldSettings.IsVisibleOnWebsite == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT visible on website");
        break;
    case Field.UserName:
        GeneralFieldSettings generalFieldSetting3 = generalFieldSettings.Single(x => x.Field == Field.UserName);
        if (generalFieldSetting3.CanSetIfIsRequired == false && companyFieldSettings.IsRequired == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT required");
        if (generalFieldSetting3.CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite == false && companyFieldSettings.IsVisibleOnWebsite == false)
            throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT visible on website");
        break;
}
```

to

```
// Declare field setting once before switch statement
GeneralFieldSettings generalFieldSetting;

// Set field setting accordingly with selected field
switch (companyFieldSettings.Field)
{
    case Field.UserEmail:
        generalFieldSetting = generalFieldSettings.Single(x => x.Field == Field.UserEmail);
        break;
    case Field.UserIdentifier:
        generalFieldSetting = generalFieldSettings.Single(x => x.Field == Field.UserIdentifier);
        break;
    case Field.UserName:
        generalFieldSetting = generalFieldSettings.Single(x => x.Field == Field.UserName);
        break;
}
// Add a condition if no match for field
if (generalFieldSetting == null)
    throw new Exception("Invalid field");
// Two below conditions moved outside of switch statement
if (!generalFieldSetting.CanSetIfIsRequired && !companyFieldSettings.IsRequired)
    throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT required");
if (!generalFieldSetting.CanSetIfVisibleOnWebsite && !companyFieldSettings.IsVisibleOnWebsite)
    throw new Exception("You can't set this field NOT visible on website");
```

I also changed your `cond == false` to `!cond` as your fields are non-nullable booleans.

Comment: Good answer. Seems to me you could also get rid of the switch statement, e.g. with `generalFieldSetting = generalFieldSettings.Single( x => x.Field == companyFieldSettings.Field)`

Comment: @JohnWu that's right, I overlooked this part! Thanks for pointing it out